# Light-weight system monitor tool/app for OSX, Conky alternatives

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, activity-monitor, geektool

On common UNIX-like computer operating systems there was extremely flexible/customizeable/lightweight tool for *System Stats monitoring*, called [`Conky`](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky). I'd like to find alternative system monitoring tool for operating system stats in **OS X**, preferable with the same set of features or more, e.g.:

- *OS stats monitoring* (CPU usage, mem usage, network monitoring, disk usage, "top" like process stats, uname, uptime, etc);
- support of *compact representation in system tray (menu bar)*, or/end desktop-widget view;
- lightweight;
- highly customizable, support of *user configuration* (alike in `conky`-app: display information either as text, or using simple progress bars and graph widgets, with different fonts and colours);

**What options for application/tools exist for OS X?**

I searched for the other topics, and found, that answers/questions are not well organized, some of them are really specialized, lots of duplicates, etc. Let's be more specific.

### Rules to structure the answer

1. One app per answer.
2. Use **this format for the first two lines** of your answer:

   > ## `[app name](link to website)`
   >
   > ### `[App Store](link to AppStore) (price)`
3. Check for duplicates before adding new answers.
4. If you find a duplicate, vote it down and encourage its poster to up-vote the original entry instead (and remove the duplicate).
5. Include short description (preferably not marketing text) about what this **system monitor** does:

   - which OS stats (uname, uptime, CPU usage, mem usage, disk usage, "top" like process stats, and network monitoring, just to name a few);
   - what are configuration options, how flexible they are;
   - can it be shown nicely/compact in system tray (menu bar);
   - can it display information either as text, or using simple progress bars and graph widgets, with different fonts and colours;
   - provide one-two screenshots, if possible (with permanent link)
   - unique features;
   - is it lightweight or monstrous;
   - etc.